# Forward URL with variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following visitors coming to my page via this link:
http://www.letsdesign.co.uk/?link=cave

We added the variable so we could monitor results from an in game link. 
We would like to forward these visitors to another URL.

We once had a javascript code for this, but we have lost it. This needs to work in the header of a wordpress site. Does anyone have the script to make this work?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in PHP, this is very simple:

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['link'] ) && $_REQUEST['link'] == "cave" ){
     header( 'location: ' . 'http://mysite.com' );
     exit();
}
```

You would simply place that above all other content in your WordPress header file. Ideally you'll include this in a PHP document referenced on all pages, or the front page (whichever you prefer).

**Alternatively,**

If you wanted to use JavaScript, you could implement something like this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if( /^(.*)[?](link=cave)(.*)$/.test( document.location.search ) )
        document.location.href = 'http://mysite.com';
</script>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code - `$REQUEST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. But you can also use `$_GET`.

Comment: You should probably be explicit with `$_GET`. Also, why the two strings being concatenated?

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of using $_REQUEST ever since I debugged an application in which the URI wasn't complete in $_GET but was in $_REQUEST :P. As for concatenation, I did it to accentuate that a variable could be placed there just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

This redirects the users to example.com if the link=cave parameter is present.

```
<script>
    if (/\blink=cave\b/.test(document.location.search)) {
        document.location.href = 'http://example.com';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can use something like:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}

var vars = getUrlVars();
if (vars['link'] == 'cave')
{
    // Redirect here
    window.location = 'http://some.other.site';
}
```

Or if you want to do it from PHP, then simply use:

```
if ($_GET['link'] == 'cave')
{
  header('Location: http://some.other.site');
  die();
}
```